# Difference between JAX-WS and Spring-WS

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, spring-ws

How are these two different from each other? As per my understanding, Spring-ws has annotations like @Endpoint, @PayloadRoot,  @RequestPayload, @ResponsePayload, etc. In JAX-WS, there are annotations like @WebService, @WebMethod, @WebParam, @WebResult, etc. which correspond to the methods for Spring-WS.

I have browsed through various links trying to explain the difference between these two approaches, but all fail to clearly do the same. Some say that JAX-WS follows only code-first approach and Spring-WS follows only contract-first approach. Is this true?

Comment: https://blog.frankel.ch/web-services-jax-ws-vs-spring